# Shipping GNU/Linux Firefox plugin with shared libraries (for installation with no root access)

Tags: linux, firefox, shared-libraries, rpath

The application is a Firefox plugin (loaded from $HOME/.mozilla/plugins), so wrapper script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not an easy option.

RPATH, as far as I know, cannot refer to $HOME and can be only absolue path.

Firefox tries to dlopen it's plugin from ~/.mozilla/plugins but fails (because it depends on shared libraries installed somewhere in the user home directory).

Modifying Firefox menu item to provide a  wrapper (with LD_LIBRARY_PATH) around Firefox is too hacky.

What should installer script do (without root access) to make standard firefox load plug-ins that depends on out shared library?

1. Should I just try to make embed everything into that .so to remove dependencies?
2. Should I try to make installer script to finish linking or patch RPATH during the installation phase?

Comment: Included `patchelf` into the installer which which patches the detected paths to the plugin that is being installed.

Comment: Removed a hack with `patchelf` and hardcoded path with $ORIGIN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set RPATH to `$ORIGIN/lib` so the loader will look for libraries relative to the my file.

Script just unpacks the plugin to `$HOME/.mozilla/plugins/myplugin.so` and libraries to `$HOME/.mozilla/plugins/lib/`

rpath can be specified to linker though the gcc by adding `Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib'` (`$` should be doubled in a Makefile) and can also be changed after compilation by `patchelf`.