# How to link to shared lib from shared lib with relative path?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I'm working on a Firefox plugin that uses external libraries to render 3D graphics on the browser.

The problem is that I want the plugin to use external libraries packed with it without changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.
The libraries are installed in a position relative to the plugin (a shared library too), while the actual executable (i.e. the browser) can be located somewhere entirely else.

I'm testing it on Ubuntu (no problem at Windows version of the plugin)
My dependencies are OpenSceneGraph libraries and static compilation will make the plugin really big (not an option if there is another one).

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015411/shipping-gnu-linux-firefox-plugin-with-shared-libraries-for-installation-with-no

Comment: Interesting, i can confirm that with a simple test program. It uses `dlopen()` to load a `lib1` and `lib1` links to a `lib2` and uses `$ORIGIN` to load it from a relative path. This works without problems.

Answer (score 29):

Use the rpath option when linking and specify the 'special' path **$ORIGIN**.

Example:

```
-Wl,-R,'$ORIGIN/../lib'
```

Here's a site that elaborates on using **$ORIGIN**:
http://www.itee.uq.edu.au/~daniel/using_origin/

Comment: the link is broken (5 years old yes I know :) )

Comment: [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130915172134/http://itee.uq.edu.au/~daniel/using_origin/) to the rescue :)

Comment: Also, [it seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) that [`chrpath`](http://man.devl.cz/man/1/chrpath) and [`patchelf`](http://man.devl.cz/man/1/patchelf) can help too (I haven't tried them yet though...)

Comment: Be careful when using `$ORIGIN` as it might be redefined somewhere else in the Makefile. In my case it was somehow set to a completely unrelated value.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the `-L` flag during the compilation to specify the relative path where the linker can find your shared objects.

If you have already generated your lib, you can link by directly invoking the `ld`command.

**Tips :**  You can easily check if some symbols are defined in a lib using the unix command `nm`. This is a useful way to check that the linking is well-done.

(If I were you, I would just change temporaly the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as you said in your post. Why don't you want to do this ?)

Comment: It is not about the linker finding the libraries, it's about the loader finding them in a location relative to the library currently being loaded (the plugin). With plugins you can't control how the host process (i.e. the browser) is invoked, thus enviroment variables won't do it. On OS X `@loader_path` does the trick, on Linux i don't know.

Comment: Ok sorry for the bad reading. Maybe the best thing to do is using language specific commands to load the lib at runtime. I will probably delete this answer tomorrow if I don't find a way to solve this properly.

Comment: The usual dynamic loading has the major disadvantage of not having the stubs, so you have to resolve the symbols manually :/

Answer (score -3):

It's wrong to use relative rpath for security reason,

You should use libdl functions (dlopen, etc)

Comment: If implemented poorly, usage of rpath can certainly cause problems, but Linux (and other systems) have built-in safeguards.  For example, under certain circumstances, ld.so will not expand ORIGIN at all.  Additionally, relative paths are absolutely necessary for relocatable programs; otherwise, you end up having to install a software package to a fixed location -- eg, being forced to install matlab to /usr/share/matlab always instead of something like /opt/matlab, or /usr/local/matlab, etc.

Comment: Furthermore, people can make informed decisions about whether to use ORIGIN expansion, particularly if the software in question is of their own creation and being used on their own hardware.