# how to link shared library from non existing(in compile time) folder

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers, ldd

i'm trying to link shared library to another shared library(protobuf) with -rpath option, the problem is that the lib is in another direcory in compile time than in runtime, and -rpath option requires an existing in compile time path. (so i get an "No such file or directory" error)
Is there any workaround for that? 
I would rather not to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here [Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)

Changing rpath after compilation solves my problem.

[edited]
There is another, better approach:  [how to link to shared lib from shared lib with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960641/how-to-link-to-shared-lib-from-shared-lib-with-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

-rpath specifies the runtime library search path.

Here is a quoate from the link [Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN95)

"
During development, there's the potential problem of modifying a library that's also used by many other programs -- and you don't want the other programs to use the `developmental''library, only a particular application that you're testing against it. One link option you might use is ld's`rpath'' option, which specifies the runtime library search path of that particular program being compiled. From gcc, you can invoke the rpath option by specifying it this way:
 -Wl,-rpath,$(DEFAULT_LIB_INSTALL_PATH)
If you use this option when building the library client program, you don't need to bother with LD_LIBRARY_PATH (described next) other than to ensure it's not conflicting, or using other techniques to hide the library. "

Comment: I know all of that, the problem is when i use -Wl,-rpath,$(DIR) the linker checks if $(DIR) path exists (when compiling) and puts error (such i described upper).
It's situation when that $(DIR) does not exist in compile time, it exists only in runtime.