# g++ not find .so files

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am trying to generate a c++ library using the g++ compiler. My library has another C library as dependency and I have compiled it in order to obtain the .so files.

I have the following structure:

```
src:
    include/linux:
        libcustom.a
        libcustom.la
        libcustom.so
        libcustom.so.0
        libcustom.so.0.0.0
```

Now, when I have all the .o files of my cpp classes, and I want to link the library, I execute the following command:

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mylibrary.so File1.o File2.o File3.o -L./include/linux -lc++ -lutil -lm -lcustom -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/include/linux' -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

But it throws me the error:

```
libcustom.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am executing the command from the `src` directory.

I know it could be fixed editing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the idea it is someone can use my library without the need of configuring anything, so I am trying to do that with the c++'s -rpath flag.

Any idea how can I fix it, or the reason for the error?

Comment: You use relative path `-Wl,-rpath=./include/linux`, which is not recognized by the `ld` loader in Linux. Use absolute path instead. For correct way of using relative path, goto http://stackoverflow.com/a/4018559/6238076

Answer (score 3):

The error message you got seems to come from the run-time loader [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) instead of the linker [`ld`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html) (I know the names are confusing). You have to distinguish between finding so's at link-time and at run-time. The -L flag you give at link-time has nothing to do with localizing the library at run-time.

Your `rpath=./include/linux` value is not correct, because *dot* is not recognized by the `ld` as relative path. Relative searching path should be given like

```
-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/include/linux'
```

where the `$ORIGIN` represents the folder where your **executable** (not `mylibrary.so`) locates. Make sure to use *single quote* and not double quote because the string `$ORIGIN` should be passed to the linker literally and hard coded into the executable file.

More details goes

1. [how to link to shared lib from shared lib with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960641/how-to-link-to-shared-lib-from-shared-lib-with-relative-path)
2. [ld: Using -rpath,$ORIGIN inside a shared library (recursive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323603/ld-using-rpath-origin-inside-a-shared-library-recursive)

Comment: You are totally right, that is the problem, because now I have tested to change the -rpath indicating the absolute path of the library and it works.

But `$ORIGIN` does not work for me, because I am using a Makevars file and it "translates" the -rpath from `-Wl,-rpath="'$$ORIGIN/include/linux'"` to `-Wl,-rpath="'/include/linux'"`. I have read the webpage attached in the post that you suggest, and I can not find the solution. Do you know how can I fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: In Makefile you need to escape the `$` symbol with `$$`: that is `-rpath='$$ORIGIN/include/linux'`

Comment: Also you don't need to double quote the path, use single quote only. Check the echo of your make command and ensure the parameter is passed to g++ correctly

Comment: Now I have written `-rpath='$$ORIGIN/include/linux'` in my Makevars, and it executes `-rpath=$ORIGIN/include/linux` without the quotes. How can add them? If I write `-rpath="'$$ORIGIN/include/linux"'` (double quotes plus single quotes) it executes `rpath=/include/linux`

Comment: Seems that you need to write `'-Wl,-rpath=\'$$ORIGIN/include/linux\''` to also escape single quote `'`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7860705/6238076

Comment: With `'-Wl,-rpath='\''$$ORIGIN/include/linux'\'''` it executes `'$ORIGIN/include/linux'` (great!), but still throwing the error because it does not find the `.so` file. Do I need to configure something else in order to use the $ORIGIN param? Sorry if I am annoying you, I appreciate a lot your help

Comment: Can you update the question including the echo of your make system (exact commands issued to g++ and the corresponding error message).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111941/discussion-between-gdlmx-and-bra-racing).