# how to fix dependency path when use python3 to import .so file?

Tags: python

I built a project to a python lib and after that I want to migrate and run the lib to server or any other machine. but I meet a dependency problem:
[image]

The .so file `cysteps_dist.so` in the lib `step` folder has some dependend .so libraries located in the temporary `build` folder. If I just copy the lib `step` folder to other machine, it won't work.

So, I want to copy these dependend libraries (example `libomega_h.so` and `libsundials_cvode.so.3` **and any potentially missing library file**) to the same `step` folder.

[image]

I want to change the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when I use `import steps` so that the copied libraries can be found.

But I don't want to use command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/steps` every time before command `import steps`. So I am looking for a way to change the `__init__.py` file or any other source file in the `step` folder to achieve this "specify env variable" effect.

I tried some code like followed but failed:

```
import os
if not 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' in os.environ:
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.path.dirname(__file__)
else:
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.path.dirname(__file__) + ":" + os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]

os.execve(os.path.realpath(__file__), (' ',), os.environ)
```

so, how to make the .so file find its dependencies in its file location?

Comment: Why don't you just place those files in `/usr/local/lib` so they are universally available?

Comment: @TimRoberts That's a good idea. I just want to know how to achive this effert and it's more like easy to deploy. and there is a another way which use some option when compiling them, but I don't want to go deep in details of these opensource libs.

Answer (score 0):

for my question, if I don't want to go deep in details of compling. I need to modify the `rpath` of the shared library.

from:[q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960641/how-to-link-to-shared-lib-from-shared-lib-with-relative-path) and [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)
I just need to install **chrpath** via `apt install chrpath`
then run commands as follows:

```
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/:'`patchelf --print-rpath cysteps_dist.so` cysteps_dist.so
patchelf --print-rpath cysteps_dist.so
```

in this case I get:

```
# patchelf --print-rpath cysteps_dist.so
/root/STEPS/build/_bundle/SUNDIALS-install/lib:/usr/lib/petscdir/petsc3.12/x86_64-linux-gnu-real/lib:/root/STEPS/build/_bundle/omega_h-install/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib:
# patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/:'`patchelf --print-rpath cysteps_dist.so` cysteps_dist.so 
# patchelf --print-rpath cysteps_dist.so 
$ORIGIN/:/root/STEPS/build/_bundle/SUNDIALS-install/lib:/usr/lib/petscdir/petsc3.12/x86_64-linux-gnu-real/lib:/root/STEPS/build/_bundle/omega_h-install/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib:
```

then I can migrate this lib to everywhere with shared libraries together.